# Trying to prove chaotic motion from the equation of a nonlinear oscillation

Tags: non-linear-systems, chaos-theory, complex-systems, integrable-systems, anharmonic-oscillators

So I'm given the equation of a nonlinear oscillation:

$x''+ω_0^2x=λx^3$

Assume that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions to the differential equation above.

Therefore;

$x = αx_1+βx_2$

$x' = αx_1'+βx_2'$

$x'' = αx_1''+βx_2''$

which can then be substituted into the given differential equation.

The problem is, I was told that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions but $x = αx_1+βx_2$ is not a solution of the differential equation, the system is considered to be chaotic.

I honestly don't know how to start solving this, any insight would be helpful.

Comment: You would have to read a lot of books on mathematics, first, I am afraid. There is no easy solution to that question. First of all, that equation is certainly not chaotic for small amplitudes and certain values of lambda.

Comment: A sum of solutions is not necessarily a solution, when we deal with a *non-linear* equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were told wrong.

When a system of differential equations is linear, if $x_1, x_2$ are solutions, then $\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2 $ is a solution.

When the system is not linear ( which is the case of your system because
of the $x^3$ term), this is not the case.
Now, nonlinear does not mean chaotic. There are nonlinear differential equations that are perfectly integrable.

Comment: But how can I determine if the system is chaotic?

Answer (score 1):

How to determine if a system is chaotic?

This depends on what you mean by "determine". If you mean to prove that it is chaotic, in the mathematical sense, this is extremely difficult and an open question for most dynamical systems. It consists to prove that there is a non zero measure set of the phase space  with positive Lyapunov exponents.

If you want to show it in the physical sense, without any rigorous demonstration, you will make a numerical simulation with numerical integration of  an ensemble of trajectories. There is no easy way to show that a dynamical system is chaotic. You cannot see it in the equations.

But here this is relatively simple as your system is a system with a phase space of  dimension 2. Using $(u,v)=(x,x')$ you can even see that your system is integrable. It is a conservative system with Hamiltonian $H (u,v)$ with

$$ 2H = v^2 +\omega_0^2 u^2 -\frac{\lambda}{2} u^4. $$

By a simple derivation

$$ 2 H' = 2 v v' +2 \omega_0^2 u v -2 \lambda u^3 v = 2v\left(v'+\omega_0^2 u -\lambda u^3 \right),$$
but with
$$ v' = x'' = -\omega_0^2 u +\lambda u^3 $$
one gets

$$ H' = 0.$$
The system is integrable and the trajectories are  the curves of equation $H(u,v)=Cte$ in the $(u,v)$ plane. In this case, there is no need to make numerical simulations, and the result is rigorous.